# Is it possible to reorder and recombine fragments in fmp4?

Tags: mp4, http-live-streaming, fmp4

I have fragmented mp4 which I want to send users through HLS. It's ok if I just send it as is. But I need opportunity to reorder fragments in this video.

For example initial video, which looks like this:
[original video format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDFtb.png)

I want reorganize fragments and get this:
[expected video format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPzvi.png)

I try make it locally, and it's work in VLS player (HLS). For this I modified sequence number for fragments in moof (mfhd). But when I try play it remotely (HLS) it does not work. I think, that some players (js) expect some additional information from each fragment, probably for example time offset. But I can not find which atom (box) contain this information. I spent a lot of time searching and I'm still at the very beginning of the problem.

I tried to modify the fragment sequence number, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "**Track Fragment Media Decode Time Box**" (**tfdt**) stores the `baseMediaDecodeTime` which is the **accumulative** decode time.

Consider the following...

- `baseMediaDecodeTime` must **increase monotonically** for each chunk.
- This means you must update (replace) the tfdt entry of chunk with expected next **tftd** entry.
- When you naively reorder the chunks, the `baseMediaDecodeTime` will be invalid.

The "**Track Fragment Media Decode Time Box**" (**tfdt**) is located inside each **moof header** at:

```
moof --> traf --> tfdt
```